# Visual defect in VirtualizingStackPanel in FlipView WP 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, flipview, virtualizingstackpanel

In my project i am working with `FlipView` with collection of images. For better performance i am using `VirtualizingStackPanel` and it working fine, but i noticed strange behavior of last item of collection in flipview. If i am scrolling to last item and then scroll back to the previous, last image sometimes disappearing for a moment as though redrawing(flickering). Here is modified flipview sample from [msdn](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-FlipView-control-0ae45312): http://1drv.ms/1d2WGzg . You can try it yourself on first page `Scenario1_Population`.

Code what i have add to this sample:

```
<FlipView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</FlipView.ItemsPanel>
```

Has anyone faced this problem before? I will be appreciate for any advice!

Comment: Have you tried to set cache to requiered ?